# How to use paintComponent in loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to draw many shapes using paint component method, but I've gotten an undesirable outcome. So… for a few seconds my frame is white and after `'Draw'== 0` it shows all my shapes in one moment. I would like to draw one shape, then wait 500ms, then draw another shape without removing previous one.

```
public package GUI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class okno3 extends JPanel{
String sb="";
int pozx,pozy,pozx2,pozy2,r,s,krztalt;
Color c;
int Draw = 3;

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
    okno3 okno = new okno3();
    Frame.setSize(768,768);
    Frame.setTitle("Projetk 3");
    Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Frame.setVisible(true);
    Frame.add(okno);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(getForeground());

    while(this.Draw>0) {
        this.Draw--;
        this.c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255));
        g.setColor(c);
        this.pozx = (int)(getWidth()*Math.random());
        this.pozy = (int)(getHeight()*Math.random());
        this.pozx2 = (int)(getWidth()*Math.random());
        this.pozy2 = (int)(getHeight()*Math.random());
        this.r =(int)(Math.random()*75)+25;
        this.s =(int)(Math.random()*75)+25;

        this.krztalt = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;

        switch(krztalt) {
            case 1:
                g.drawOval(pozx, pozy, r, s);
            break;
            case 2:
                g.drawRect(pozx, pozy, r, s);
            break;
            case 3:
                g.drawLine(pozx, pozy, pozx2, pozy2);
            break;
        }
        try{
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Wynik.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            String sb = krztalt + " " + pozx + " " + pozy + " " + r + " " + s + " " + c;
            this.sb = sb + "\n" + this.sb;
            fstream.write(this.sb);
            fstream.close();

            out.close();
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not sleep inside a `paintComponent` method or any other method that runs in the EDT.  The EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) is a single thread used to process events and other sequential tasks such as painting.  So none of your changes will show until after you leave `paintComponent`.

You need to do all of your calculations outside of `paintComponent` and then every 500 milliseconds, invoke `repaint()` and have the `paintComponent` repaint them. It is best to use a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to wait between repaint calls.

Check out [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) in the Java Tutorials and search this site for more information on painting and the Event Dispatch Thread.